# Why does attaching dplyr change my data.frame's structure?

Tags: r, dplyr

Two scripts, identical except the 2nd includes `library(dplyr)`. The one without dplyr attached gives the result I expect:

```
library(readxl)

#PM Golfers 2015. Last names in col 4, first in col 5
X2015_Golfer_List <- read_excel("./data/2015 Golfer List.xlsx")
name <- paste(trimws(X2015_Golfer_List[,5]),trimws(X2015_Golfer_List[,4]))

#AM Golfers 2015. Last names in col 3, first in col 4
XMorning_Golfer_2015 <- read_excel("./data/Morning golfers.xlsx")
name2 <-paste(trimws(XMorning_Golfer_2015[,4]),    
              trimws(XMorning_Golfer_2015[,3]))

name <- c(name,name2) 
d <- data.frame(name,g15=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

`str(d)` gives the results I expect:

```
'data.frame':   137 obs. of  2 variables:
$ name: chr  "Harold Kaplan" "Steve Schachtman" "Les Novak" "Ken Raskin" ...
$ g15 : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

If I attach dplyr and make no other changes,

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

#PM Golfers 2015. Last names in col 4, first in col 5
X2015_Golfer_List <- read_excel("./data/2015 Golfer List.xlsx")
name <- paste(trimws(X2015_Golfer_List[,5]),trimws(X2015_Golfer_List[,4]))

#AM Golfers 2015. Last names in col 3, first in col 4
XMorning_Golfer_2015 <- read_excel("./data/Morning golfers.xlsx")
name2 <- paste(trimws(XMorning_Golfer_2015[,4]),
               trimws(XMorning_Golfer_2015[,3]))

name <- c(name,name2) 
d <- data.frame(name,g15=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

then when I source, I get these warnings:

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
    filter, lag
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.3.2
```

which seem not to be relevant to my code. Then `str(d)` gives

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ name: chr  "c(\"Harold\", \"Steve\", \"Les\", \"Ken\", \"Stan\", \"Paul\", \"Ron\", \"Drew\", \"Peter\", \"Stuart\", \"Mike\", \"Rick\", \""| __truncated__ "c(\"Rick\", \"Howard\", \"Gary\", \"Sandy\", \"Peter\", \"Tom\", \"Andy\", \"Robert\", \"Marvin\", \"Thomas\", \"Stuart\", \"Ho"| __truncated__
 $ g15 : logi  TRUE TRUE
```

It seems the data.frame is now considering the original name vector as a row and the name2 vector as a second row, but I don't understand why, since I haven't changed anything. Or more properly, I don't understand what I changed when I attached dplyr.

One more note: I tried to reproduce this more simply with

```
name <- c('a','b','c')
name2 <- c('d','e','f')
name <- c(name,name2)
d <- data.frame(name,g15=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

but when I did that, I got the same (correct) results both with and without dplyr attached. So it must have something to do with the class that is returned from `read_excel`. But `class(name)` and `class(name2)` just return "character" in all cases so I can't see what it is that's different.

Thanks - I am enjoying learning R but this kind of thing is challenging.

Comment: It's actually not `dplyr`, it's [`tibble`](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble), which is imported by `dplyr`, but not by `readxl`. `read_excel` technically returns a tibble, but if tibble isn't loaded, the extra class doesn't do anything, and it behaves as a normal data.frame. In this case, I believe that's causing problems because you're relying on subsetting to a single column do drop from a data.frame to a vector, [which tibbles (when behaving as such) don't do](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html). Use `$` or `[[` subsetting and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ah! So loading dplyr allows the tibble to start being a tibble. Until dplyr is loaded, the proto-tibble is acting as a normal data.frame. Ok this makes sense - thank you!